# Parallel Foreach inside azure function

Tags: c#, azure-functions, task-parallel-library, azure-functions-runtime

My goal is to watch for new zip blob in a container then unzip a file in az function,push the unzipped files back in different az blob container. I have  deployed my code in a app service plan az function. I used this as my starting base 
http://www.frankysnotes.com/2019/02/how-to-unzip-automatically-your-files.html?m=1

I converted for each below to parallel.foreach with max 4 thread, works great locally on vscode with storage emulator. When i deploy it doesn't run the parrell.foreach part at all.

```
[FunctionName("Unzipthis")]
public static async Task Run([BlobTrigger("input-files/{name}", Connection = "cloud5mins_storage")]CloudBlockBlob myBlob, string name, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name:{name}");

    string destinationStorage = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("destinationStorage");
    string destinationContainer = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("destinationContainer");

    try{
        if(name.Split('.').Last().ToLower() == "zip"){

            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(destinationStorage);
            CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(destinationContainer);

            using(MemoryStream blobMemStream = new MemoryStream()){

                await myBlob.DownloadToStreamAsync(blobMemStream);

                using(ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(blobMemStream))
                {
                    foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries)
                    {
                        log.LogInformation($"Now processing {entry.FullName}");

                        //Replace all NO digits, letters, or "-" by a "-" Azure storage is specific on valid characters
                        string valideName = Regex.Replace(entry.Name,@"[^a-zA-Z0-9\-]","-").ToLower();

                        CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(valideName);
                        using (var fileStream = entry.Open())
                        {
                            await blockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(fileStream);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        log.LogInformation($"Error! Something went wrong: {ex.Message}");

    }            
}
```

Comment: Use of Parallel.ForEach on functions may not work as expected depending on the machine you run it on (your own app service vs consumption).  Perhaps related to this GitHub issue:  https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/815

Comment: Don't use Parallel.ForEach inside Azure, Azure Function host run multiple task-parallel (in your case multiple blob processing in parallel). it will overkill your application processing and single thread execution time.